# Missing ENUM in org.apache.poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to work with **org.apache.poi** for xls/xlsx processing.
(Springboot)

I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/FileMagic
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:208)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:98)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
    at ua.siemens.dbtool.service.impl.ExcelServiceImpl.getTemplate(ExcelServiceImpl.java:159)
    at ua.siemens.dbtool.service.impl.ExcelServiceImpl.exportTimesheet(ExcelServiceImpl.java:69)
    at ua.siemens.dbtool.controller.TimesheetController.exportTimesheet(TimesheetController.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 108 common frames omitted
```

The method:

```
private XSSFWorkbook getTemplate() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File xlsTemplate = new File(classLoader.getResource(XLS_TEMPLATE).getFile());

    return new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(xlsTemplate));
}
```

In my **pom.xml**:

```
<!--EXCEL-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

I couldn't find **FileMagic** in **org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem** package, i don't know why it is not there. Docs say it must be there: [link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/class-use/FileMagic.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem seems to be that FileMagic doesn't exist in Version 3.9 of `poi`.

Using Version 3.17

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

should do the trick.

Also it's probably a good idea to have the same Version for `poi` and `poi-oomxl`.

Comment: yes you are right, I forgot to check the simplest :)